How can I bring back my whistle register? (male)
Around February 2023 I discover my whistle. I was 14 years old that time. Overtime, I used to sing with it, literally enjoying it since I am able to sing Mariah's High note. My whistle is ranged to about A5 to A7, airy, healthy and I have a knowledge using it.
In February 2024, it started to weaken since I am very busy in school, until I forgot about my whistle register.
Now I am 16 years old, and I am trying hard to bring back my register before I reach 18 years old. When I'm practicing "how and wow" exercise, it only produces air with a small portion of squeak sound, like high frequency. How can I bring back my whistle register?

Did your voice break between when you were 14 and now? If it did, I'm afraid we might not be able to help you, as your vocal range will have gone down significantly.

Seems like an advanced technique like this would strongly suggest finding a qualified teacher to help you.

Wait, this is actually about singing? Not whistling? I got a long ways in before I understood that. But to echo @Dekkadeci's point, "my voice changed as I got older" is to be expected, in many various ways.

@AndyBonner to me it reads quite clearly about whistle register (very high) of singing voice.

Same thing happened to me, around the same age.  Getting that register back might not be an achievable goal.  But I'm interested in any answers.

“In February 2024, it started to weaken since I am very busy in school” ... that might not be the reason. Your voice will develop into your adult voice until about 21 years. In this time a lot changes, and your voice will not be the same as it was. This does not mean you’re necessarily going to be unable to do what was possible before. But it will require changes in the approach. Having been able to do it before is both good and bad. It gives you a point to start from, but it will also force you into doing things a way your brain has learned before that don’t work anymore.

... So I guess it is important to not think too much about “I’m trying to product whistle”, but start from what worked and try to evaluate how changing thing affects the result. When you find something that works, try to control it. But as soon as you think: “Product whistle notes” your brain will intuitively force what it has learned.

Growth spurt in adolescence changes many aspects in our bodies, sometimes even in irrecoverable ways, including the conformation of vocal cords.
Most "adjustments" we do are achieved instinctively, because they're part of everyday routines (eg: walking, handling objects) or are based on constant body awareness (even if not at a completely conscious level).
Even assuming that yours was actually a whistle register, there's no guarantee that you'll ever be able to get it back, especially after so much time of missing practice: body changes in adolescence may be quite dramatic over a short time period, and even a few months of missing practice (which considers awareness of those changes) may be compared to years of similar missing practice for an adult, when that gap coincides with relevant changes in your body structure.
In some ways, one has to learn again to do things they gave as easy and granted, and previous experience may not always be enough.
Little is known about the physiological production of whistle tones, but, at least statistically, it's rarely achieved by male singers (probably due to the "thickness" of vocal cords in males).
Also, being able to achieve that level of body control often requires a relatively advanced level of proprioception, which is not immediate to get even for body parts that we can see.
It is not impossible, though: the related Wikipedia page lists a few male singers allegedly using that singing tone, including a Guinness Record holder that, despite his achievements, clearly has difficulties in controlling it accurately:



If you care about your voice, don't try to force it without any understanding of its mechanisms (which, as said, are little known), or you'll risk damaging your vocal cords, possibly permanently.
If you really want to try to get back that register, prepare yourself for a long, difficult (and possibly dangerous) journey in which you will have to find a very good teacher that will try to help you in pushing your limits, but still within safe limits.
Yet, be aware: as already said, it is possible that you won't be able to get that back at all.

The OP doesn't have "many years of missing practice". It's been 9 months since Feb 2024.

@user1079505 You're right. Yet, we have to consider two important aspects. 1. that date reference may be considered as possibly biased: when the OP arguably states (remembers?) that they noticed the difference; unless they are able to provide accurate and consistent records of their capabilities, it's an assumption, especially considering their school business (for what we know, that degradation may have started many months before as well). 2. body changes in adolescence can be huge: even a couple of months of missing physical practice at that age can be virtually likened to years.
